# Rigged body appears distorted when moving

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I finally copied off the bones of a character I ripped from SFM, but when I rig them to the mesh itself (automatic weights option), when i move it in pose mode, it's heavily distorted aside from lower areas in the legs. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems that, some parts of your mesh are not attached to the bones,
Please try to use the **Weight paint** mode to add missing part of mesh to the respective bone.

Steps are shown below:

[image]

[image]
Red means full control, blue means no control, and in between those color, partial controls.

Comment: You are welcome, Please accept the answer, so it may be useful for others too. :)